# Site name gets cropped while looking at user profiles on international Stack Overflow sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, internationalization

[image]

I can't see the complete 'en español' underneath the Spanish Stack Overflow logo on user profile pages. Nothing changes when I scroll, but when I go to the [home page](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), the logo gets shifted up a bit and it looks fine. The same thing happens on the [Russian Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) site.

You can tell that the logo is the correct image but shifted downwards because the top of the 'in [language]' text is visible:

[image]

I'm on Vivaldi 2.0 for Windows 10 and on Chrome 69.0.3497.100 for Windows 10. It happens only when you don't have an account *for that site*, both when you're anonymous and when you have connected accounts on other sites.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome for Mac. What version of Chrome? Do you have any addons that might be interfering with this?

Comment: @Catija It's chrome 69.0.3497.100 for Windows 10 (I think that's the latest Chrome). I'm sure don't have any addons, userscripts, or extensions on Chrome, but I have SOX (stack overflow extras) on Vivaldi.

Comment: I do see it when I'm not logged in (in incognito).

Comment: I'm also using Chrome 69 on Windows 10 and I'm not able to reproduce this on [es.so] but I was able on [ru.so].

Comment: @Rubén are you looking at profile pages or the home page? Could you perhaps tell me what you see for [this random profile](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/282637/ver-nick)

Comment: @Chair I edited my previous comment. I'm looking at the profile pages, "obviously" :)

Comment: @Rubén perhaps it's something about you having an account on es.stackoverflow. I viewed it with that semi-signed in state where I get notifications from other sites by I can't vote through the association bonus (I haven't made accounts on any international sites).

Comment: @Chair You are right, I have an account on [es.so] but not on [ru.so]. I think that you should update your question to include that you don't have accounts on the referred sites and it will be even better if you include the complete top bar to show the "Join" button instead of the tools for joined users.

Comment: @Rubén Yep, my current claims about which sites I was signed in for is misleading/incorrect. That explains why Catija wasn't able to observe it initially. I've edited it; hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: So, it's worth noting that Vivaldi [isn't a supported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), which means you'll likely have a few problems. Hopefully fixing this for users who aren't logged in will fix it for you in Vivaldi, though. If not, then I'm afraid it's a matter of your browser choice.

Comment: @Catija Nah, I don't think Vivaldi would be the problem: it's largely based on Chromium. I've explored this a bit more, and the skewed logo shows up under the same circumstances and looks the same with both Vivaldi and Chrome, so it's a safe assumption that fixing it for chrome will fix Vivaldi. Honestly, I'm not too invested in this bug because I don't use any international sites, but I just thought I'd bring it up in case there's anybody else who notices. Anyways, it's good to hear that the team'll look at this (even though I'm sure it's not top-priority since it's minor cosmetics). Thanks!

Comment: @Catija I've got the same issue with Chrome 71 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Also confirm issue with Firefox 64 on Ubuntu 16.04 on ru, pt, and es stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

After a good bit of hunting, looks like the issue is really quite simple (though of course, on the server end I don't know...)

Looks like the logo is lacking the `_glyph` css class in the html.  To prove this, you can simply inspect the nonfunctional logo and add the _glyph class to it.  A couple of screenshots show it all:

#### Inspect Element:

[image: Inspecting element]

#### Add _glyph class:

[image: Adding _glyph class]

#### Tada!

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Good catch! If only it was so simple... as far I as came to learn, SE developed super complex mechanism for their CSS, and even out sourced part of it. It's HUGE, and I'm pretty sure any tiny change has huge chance to cause bugs elsewhere. So even such small change will have to be reviewed like 100 of times, and take days to implement, if they even decide to try and do it. (Which I doubt they'll do, having higher priority things to do.)

Comment: Yeah... I was kind of afraid that might be the case.  :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Eh? Our styles aren't outsourced. Having said that, I thought we fixed this... but apparently not. I'll check on it this week.

Comment: @AdamLear not styles themselves, the CSS render engine, forgot its name. No?

Comment: @ShadowWizard you mean their framework *Stacks*?

Comment: @MEE yeah, [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah right, that's not outsourced. :) It's open source, but it's developed in-house by our designers.

Comment: @AdamLear oh, oops. I meant open sourced. :)

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed. The site logo at the top of all pages should now be shown in its entirety, for both logged-in and anonymous users (it had been cut off on some pages for international sites, for anonymous users, as reported on [meta.ja.so](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2992)). The solution did indeed involve making sure that the `_glyph` class was being applied appropriately.

---

> the top bar logo
> appears in all its glory
> for anon users