# In user profiles on meta (SO-only?), the site's meta logo is partially hidden (by the search bar?)

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, top-bar

So far I've only seen this on Stack Overflow, which is probably due to its topbar design being different than most of the network, but in case there might be more sites impacted, I'm reporting it here on main Meta.

If I open [a user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) on MSO today, this is what I see (Windows 10, Firefox 64.0); the `w` in `Stack Overflow` sees one of its "bars" slightly hidden.

> [image: w letter of Stack Overflow is partially hidden]

It used not to be the case, as evidenced by [this archived version of the same profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20191127193729/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray):

> [image: Former version, everything looks fine]

---

Browsing MSE and MSO for `[bug] logo`, `[bug] user profile` and other variations did not yield an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Works for me (similar system). Also that logo is missing the orange word "meta" in the logo.

Comment: @Tim I _think_ the "meta" word being excluded is [status-by-design]. Otherwise, curious that you don't have the issue. I don't think it's a userscript breaking the page, I have none active on MSO.

Comment: Well, I see the "meta" word in the logo :D

Comment: @Tom from the user profile pages?

Comment: Yes, it looks like I see it on every page on MSO.

Comment: Jenayah, I'm using Firefox Android and agree with @Tom. I see the opposite of what you are complaining about, the Archive.Org version is not "All good!"; it has the bug about which you are complaining - the live (non-archived) view is normal, as far as *this* bug goes, the inability to zoom all the way out cuts off the right side (and that's already reported). Also if I turn off the left sidebar it's still good. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIKHQ.jpg

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome, had to be logged out though.

Comment: Could this be related to this design bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316661/? That also showed up only for signed-out users on profiles, except that was the bottom of the logo and it was on international sites.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome for iOS when logged out.